# React Chartist component onTouchMove Events not firing

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

I tried asking this question before but the way I asked it was so confusing that I didn't get any help.  I originally thought it was React to blame for my touchmove events to ceasefire when updating subcomponents.  I now am pretty sure it is the Chartist.js library, or possibly how I'm wrapping chartist into a react component, that is stopping the action.

Instead of rambling on about my question I've created two JSfiddles.  One that shows you can create a React slider that updates it's values continuously, regardless of being called from mousemove or touchmove.

http://jsfiddle.net/higginsrob/uf6keps2/

```
// please follow the link for full example
```

The Second fiddle implements my react wrapper for chartist, and a simplified example of how I'm using it.  When you click/drag on the chart it will select the data point at the current x value.  This is working fine with a mouse, but trying it on mobile touch devices (or chrome's mobile emulator) it will only fire a few times, and only update the chart once.

http://jsfiddle.net/higginsrob/Lpcg1c6w/

```
// please follow the link for full example
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I can't seem to reproduce your problem with Chrome Mobile Emulator; I can click around the chart a ton and it works fine. What mobile/ Chrome version are you using?

Comment: Clicking is fine, the desired effect is to slide finger across a chart and the values update continuously, the same way that mouse drag is working.  Thanks for taking a look, but after a month of messing with this I finally fixed this issue.  I'll post an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you need to put a transparent div in front of the chartist chart that captures the mousedown/touchstart, mousemove/touchmove, and mouseup/touchend events.

working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/higginsrob/jwhbzgrb/

```
// updated event functions: 

onTouchStart: function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.is_touch = (evt.touches);
    var node = evt.currentTarget.previousSibling;
    var grid = node.querySelector('.ct-grids');
    var bbox = grid.getBBox();
    this.columnwidth = bbox.width / this.props.data.length;
    this.offset = this.getScrollLeftOffset(node) + bbox.x + (this.columnwidth / 2);
    this.istouching = true;
    this.onTouchMove(evt);
}

onTouchMove: function (evt) {
    if(this.istouching){
        var x;
        if (this.is_touch) {
            if(evt.touches && evt.touches[0]){
                x = evt.touches[0].clientX - this.offset;
            }
        } else {
            x = evt.clientX - this.offset;
        }
        this.setState({
            index: Math.round(x / this.columnwidth)
        });
    }
}

onTouchEnd: function(evt){
    this.istouching = false;
}

// updated render function: 

render: function () {

    return React.DOM.div(
        {
            style: {
                position: "relative"
            }
        },

        ReactChartist({ ... your chartist chart here .... }),


        // this div sits in front of the chart and captures events

        React.DOM.div({
            onMouseDown: this.onTouchStart,
            onTouchStart: this.onTouchStart,
            onMouseMove: this.onTouchMove,
            onTouchMove: this.onTouchMove,
            onMouseUp: this.onTouchEnd,
            onTouchEnd: this.onTouchEnd,
            style: {
                position: "absolute",
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0
            }
        })
    );
}
```